# How to create an App Indicator icon in Ubuntu 14+ without using libappindicator?

Tags: unity, php, indicator, dbus

I'm trying my hand at writing simple desktop utility apps in PHP and wxWidgets using [wxPHP](http://wxphp.org/). After some substantial effort (and 20+ minutes of compilation time) to generate the PHP `wxwidgets.so` module, I thought I'd start with a simple status indicator. I am running PHP 5.5.9 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I asked [a question on *Stack Overflow*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33848681/472495), and have been appending additional research as I await answers. It turns out that it isn't straightforward in recent versions of Ubuntu, since (a) versions after 11.x [operated a whitelist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14545805/472495) to permit ordinary `wxTaskBarIcon` icons to appear, and (b) since 13.10 `wxTaskBarIcon` icons do not appear at all, and Ubuntu requires special treatment.

I find that [there is a hack](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/how-to-get-systray-whitelist-back-in.html) to bring the whitelist back to 14.x but it requires tinkering with the trusted repos, and in any case I'd rather just do it properly.

I see from *Ask Ubuntu* that there are questions on [how to find the PID of the live status icons](https://askubuntu.com/q/185991/246048), and [how to add menu items to the session ("cog") applet](https://askubuntu.com/q/188077/246048). These both make use of DBus calls from the command line. Tantalisingly there is a question on [exactly what I want to achieve](https://askubuntu.com/q/13197/246048) but the answers rely on `libappindicator`, for which PHP does not have bindings available.

I therefore think there must be DBus calls I can make from the console (and ergo from a PHP application also) but the documentation for this sits somewhere between thin and non-existent. I've tried browsing various items of source code on GitHub, but short of searching for a few `freedesktop.org` command strings, I don't really know what I am looking for. I also draw a blank with [the official documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators), unless I am missing something really obvious.

My questions therefore are: can an Application Indicator be created using DBus calls on the command line, and if so, how? I want to play with icons, text, menus and anything the system indicators can do. Or, if DBus is not the way to go about things, how can I do what `libappindicator` does, given that I don't have bindings for that library for my preferred language?

---

Edit: I've added a self-answer to my question on Stack Overflow, indicating that the best available solution at present is to build a separate indicator app in Python and open up a communication channel between that and the wxPHP app.

However, I will keep this question open, since it is slightly different - how to achieve the same ends, from PHP, using DBus. (I expect I can work out how to send DBus messages in PHP, but the format is what I would need).